# How can I use threads to get a better performance in python

Tags: python

I wrote a short code that just generate random numbers and allocate them in arrays.
Is there a way to make the timers that I print be lower with threads?

Im relatively new in python so if you know how I would love for some pointers :)

```py
import struct
import os
import time

import numpy as np

data_lines = 3000000

buff_x2 = np.random.rand(4 * data_lines)
buff_y2 = np.random.rand(4 * data_lines)
buff_z2 = np.random.rand(4 * data_lines)
buff_r2 = np.random.rand(data_lines)
buff_g2 = np.random.rand(data_lines)
buff_b2 = np.random.rand(data_lines)

start = time.time()
buff_x_breakdown = [buff_x2[i:i + 4] for i in range(0, 4 * data_lines, 4)]
buff_y_breakdown = [buff_y2[i:i + 4] for i in range(0, 4 * data_lines, 4)]
buff_z_breakdown = [buff_z2[i:i + 4] for i in range(0, 4 * data_lines, 4)]
buff_r_breakdown = [buff_r2[i] for i in range(0, data_lines, 1)]
buff_g_breakdown = [buff_g2[i] for i in range(0, data_lines, 1)]
buff_b_breakdown = [buff_b2[i] for i in range(0, data_lines, 1)]
end = time.time()
print(end - start)
xyz = np.zeros((data_lines, 3))
colors = np.zeros((data_lines, 3))

start = time.time()
for i in range(data_lines):
    xyz[i, 0] = buff_x_breakdown[i][0]
    xyz[i, 1] = buff_y_breakdown[i][0]
    xyz[i, 2] = buff_z_breakdown[i][0]

    colors[i, 0] = float(buff_r_breakdown[i]) / 255.0
    colors[i, 1] = float(buff_g_breakdown[i]) / 255.0
    colors[i, 2] = float(buff_b_breakdown[i]) / 255.0

end = time.time()
print(end - start)
```

Comment: Threads are only useful for I/O bound applications; if all you do is computations, then using threads will reduce performance since they're all running inside the same process, but you impose additional overhead due to thread switching. You can use however [multiprocessing](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html), which also has its overhead but for large computations it might pay off, on multicore machines.

Comment: Looking at your code, however, I think it would be better to make sure that all your computations are nicely vectorized and stay inside Numpy. For example what's the purpose of `buff_r_breakdown = [buff_r2[i] for i in range(0, data_lines, 1)]`? That's a super inefficient way to convert `buff_r2` to a list, but why would you want to do that in the first place? Also `buff_x_breakdown = [buff_x2[i:i + 4] for i in range(0, 4 * data_lines, 4)]` is better spelled as `buff_x_breakdown = np.random.rand(size=(data_lines, 4))` directly.

Comment: Hey, first of all thanks for the insightful information.
the original code has bytes in it that I get from the shared-memory.
so when I write this line `buff_x_breakdown = [buff_x2[i:i + 4] for i in range(0, 4 * data_lines, 4)]` Its actually has bytes in it and then I convert it to float with struct.unpack: `xyz[i, 0] = struct.unpack('f', buff_x_breakdown[i])[0]` 
`

Comment: I believe Numpy can do that as well. If you post your original code, resembling the original problem, then answers can be much more accurate.